# Disabling a Bootstrap table row on click and have it save in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that will be populated with user information based on a form they fill out. One thing I'm wanting to do is have the admin be able to "archive" a table row once they're done with that user.

The two ways I've thought I could do this is either grey out the specific table row when the archive button on that row is clicked, OR have that row move down to a different table, one specifically used for archived users.

I don't want the user's info to be deleted, just archived in case the admin needs it again

The biggest thing here is mainly to have it save.

Here is my current table from my index.html.erb file:

```
<table id="table-current" width="100%" data-toggle="table" class="table">
  <h3>Current Submissions</h3>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Email</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Phone Number</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Pick Up Address</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">City</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Pick Up Date</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Pick Up Time</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Instructions</th>
      <th data-sortable="false">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <td><%= client.first_name %> <%= client.last_name %></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:<%= client.email %>"><%= client.email %></a></td>
        <td><a href="tel:<%= client.phone_number %>"><%= number_to_phone(client.phone_number) %></a></td>
        <td><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=<%= client.pick_up_location %>&t=m" target="_blank"><%= client.pick_up_location %></a></td>
        <td><%= client.city %></td>
        <td><%= client.pick_up_date %></td>
        <td><%= client.pick_up_time.strftime("%l:%M %p") %></td>
        <td><%= client.instructions %></td>
        <td class="table-options">
          <%= link_to edit_client_path(client) do %>
            <i class="ion-edit"></i>
          <% end %>
          <button class="archive">
            <i class="ion-ios-box"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paranoia is a nice gem, but one caveat is that it overrides ActiveRecord's `destroy` method (https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/blob/92505787662e0415f228a3507a885ba771058ff1/lib/paranoia.rb#L72).

If you are comfortable with that, paranoia is a perfectly fine gem.

Another option is to roll your own strategy. Paranoia essentially just adds another column to your model to fill in when you call destroy. Alternatively, you could add your own column, perhaps something like `archived`, and make it a boolean value (or you could use `archived_at` with a timestamp, like the gem). I like to use affirmatives in my models, so I might call the column `active`, which defaults to `true` when a new record is created, and is changed to `false` when I would like to archive a record.

Now you could use your ajax link and process attached to your table to send a message back to the controller to update that new column when a user wants to archive a record. Finally, you would add logic in your table to display or hide (or gray out if you prefer) records based on this new column, either in the table, or by creating a scope on the class and sending only the scoped collection to the view:

**app/models/client.rb**

```
class Client

  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :archived, -> { where(active: false) }

  ...
end
```

**app/controllers/clients_controller.rb**

```
class ClientsController

  def index
    @clients = Client.active
  end
  ...
end
```

If you want to display all the records but just gray out the row you could add a conditional class to the table row:

```
<tr class="table-row <%= ‘archived’ unless client.active? %>">
```

Where you would style your class "archived" as you please. There are several ways to accomplish this part, this is just one example.

Comment: I had a mini epiphany and thought about doing this right after posting this question lol. I'm gonna give this a shot!

Comment: when you say "Now you could use your ajax link and process", how could I do this? I'm not the most familiar with ajax.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, when I was reading this post I thought you mentioned using Ajax but i see that was something the other answer mentioned. To be clear, you don’t need Ajax to do this, you can do it the standard way of updating your model and calling the redirect which reloads the page. Ajax is for when you want the process to be asynchronous, in an instance like this, giving the appearance that a field is archived without showing the reload.

Comment: Kind of long for a comment to provide an example, but I recommend this example for an intro: https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I would also check out other stack overflow posts on using Ajax to “toggle”characteristics on rails pages

Comment: Ok! I got it to change the column from true to false, but it's having a tough time with adding the archived class. It's saying archived is an undefined variable.

Comment: Updated my answer - your class name should be in quotes so it evaluates to a string. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ah no worries! I should've known. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to maintain separate table for this.

https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia

Take a look at this Gem. The thing you want is Soft Delete. By adding deleted_at in respective table. Use ajax based deletion so you would be able to show row as archived by Grey Out the entire row.

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <tr class="table-row" id="client_<%= client.id %>">
      <td><%= client.first_name %> <%= client.last_name %></td>
      <td class="table-options">
        <%= link_to edit_client_path(client) do %>
          <i class="ion-edit"></i>
        <% end %>
        <button class="archive">
          <i class="ion-ios-box"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

You can assign a unique id to your row. Then use the js.erb to use the AJAX functionality.